# Can't add Javascript files

Tags: magento-1.7, javascript, xml

I'm trying to add a custom Javascript file and a jQuery file to my site. I've place the following code in my `local.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <default>
        <reference name="head">
            <action method="addJs"><script>lib/jquery-1.10.2.min.js</script></action>
            <action method="addItem"><type>skin_js</type><name>js/main.js</name></action>
        </reference>
    </default>
</layout>
```

But that didn't work. Then I added the lines to `page.xml`

```
<block type="page/html_head" name="head" as="head"> 
    <action method="addJs"><script>lib/jquery-1.10.2.min.js</script></action>
    <action method="addItem"><type>skin_js</type><name>js/main.js</name></action>
</block>
```

But that didn't do the trick either. Eventhough the I have the cache disabled,I did flush it again and I even rebuild the indexes. Now i've run out of ideas to try.

Comment: are you sure you are editing the correct theme?

Comment: @Marius yes, I am using the default modern theme

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sometime theme did not load additem function. you need to add manually

Go to

http://nwdthemes.com/2014/09/25/adding-javascript-magento-head-block/

Comment: explain the answer briefly and then link to source later don't add one line answers.

Comment: @Sarfaraz Ali Thank you! I thought additem function was a standard Magento function